# vb.net Apps that work on windows 7, when executed on windows 10 the form objects dissapear

Tags: vb.net, windows

I really have a problem. I have an application that works fine on windows 7, but when I run on windows 10, some forms  when loaded all the objects dissapear. I already deactivated the UAC control, and set the ldr64.exe setwow.

Can any one help me?

Comment: Have you tried all of the various compatability settings. In particular "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings"

Comment: Where can I find this particular setting?

Comment: I typed "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings windows 10" into google and this was the first entry: http://www.howtogeek.com/175664/how-to-make-the-windows-desktop-work-well-on-high-dpi-displays-and-fix-blurry-fonts/

Comment: I' already found the definition, but it doesn't work!